# Mongoose and express.js database access within routes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

So I've been trying to switch from MySQL to MongoDB for my database. I've been trying to figure out how to use Mongoose, but every example I look at has code distributed across several files using module.exports.

Really all I want to do is use Mongoose to connect to MongoDB within my routes and save and retrieve data.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local')

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    owner: String
    ...etc
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Model', schema);

app.post('/', function (req,res)
{
    var data = new GameModel({
         name: "foo",
         owner: "bar"
    });
    data.save(function (err, data)
    {
    });
});
```

This code doesn't work.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

How should I be structuring my application?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with this, apart from the reference `GameModel` instead of `Model` which I assume is just a typo here.  Whatever is wrong must be in the missing code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It turns out "options" is reserved by Mongoose for Schemas. Which was no where in the documentation. But I figured it out after a couple hours of debugging.

Comment: Ah yes, if that was in the question I might have been able to tell you that one.  Ran into the same issue a while back.